# Convert multirelational graphs to bipartite graphs with networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx, pytorch-geometric, graph-neural-network

I have a multi-relational graph G (subject `s` and object `o` nodes connected with an edge having a predicate label `p`), made with `networkx.DiGraph`. Is there a way to easily and elegantly create its bipartite graph by replacing each labeled edge `(s, p, o)` with two unlabeled edges `{(s,p),(p,o)}`? This operation is also called Levi transformation (Levi, 1942) and is aimed to treat each entity and relation equally.

Current graph construction example:

```
amr_graph = networkx.DiGraph()

for node_id, node_string in amr.nodes.items():
   amr_graph.add_node(node_id, name=node_string)

for subj, pred, obj in amr.edges:
   amr_graph.add_edge(subj, obj, key=pred)
```

Comment: Isn't it already bipartite? Could you provide an example and the code you are using to create the graph? Basically you change the data for the graph construction or late iterate over the edges and add the nodes and edges.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I have edited the question by adding the requested details.

Comment: Thanks for that, it would be best to provide some data as well, the task and answer seem quite easy, posing the question is the hard part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create the new edges as you see fit:

```
import random
import networkx as nx

s=[random.randint(0,2) for i in range(10)]
o=[random.randint(3,5) for i in range(10)]
p=[random.randint(6,8) for i in range(10)]

G = nx.DiGraph()
H = nx.DiGraph()
F = nx.DiGraph()

#split while constructing the orgiginal graph
for subj, pred, obj in zip(s,p,o):
    G.add_edge(subj, obj, key= pred)

    H.add_edge(subj, pred, key = obj)
    H.add_edge(pred, obj, key= subj)
               
#use existing graph to split edges              
for subj, obj, d in G.edges(data=True):
    pred = d['key']

    F.add_edge(subj, pred, key = obj)
    F.add_edge(pred, obj, key= subj)
```